# How to undo Lightbox and make image not clickable

Tags: css, lightbox

I'm writing a so called "media tag" (think plugin) for IPB forum to convert a link into flash object. Part of it is the image that is there only as a decoration. The problem is that IPB does it's parsing and turns my ...

```
<img src="img.png">
```

into ...

```
<span rel="lightbox">
<img class="bbc_img" src="image.png">
</span>
```

where bbc_img is defined ...

```
img.bbc_img {
max-width: 700px !important;
max-height: 700px !important;
}
```

This wrapping is done automatically and I can't prevent it. The result is that what's supposed to be simple image, becomes clickable lightbox object and of course clicking it pops modal window with image and options to save it and close popup. And **I don't want this effect**, I just needs it to stay simple, unclickable, "dumb" image.

What I can't do is affect the page globally like inserting anything into header - I'm just inserting my code into the part of the forum post. I also can't insert "< script >" cause it automatically gets deleted (ignored) by the parser. Basically I can only work "from the inside".

What I can do is inline styles to image tag and inline javascript (there's also support for jQuery, Prototype and Scriptaculous) but only as an "onclick" event.

So, given limitations, is there a way to make my image "just image"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

event.stopPropagation();Just add on the image

```
<pre>
<img onclick='if(event!=null)event.stopPropagation();return false;' />
</pre>
```

should work.

You can change thee cursor by adding

```
style='cursor:default'
```

See [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp)

Comment: Fixed. (Checked on chrome)

Comment: It works. The mouse cursor is still changed into a hand indicating a link (not a big deal), but clicking produces no action. I would gladly upvote your answer, but being new on SO with less than 15 rep myself, I can't do it :(